# jQuery sortable receive events

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable

I have an li list with jQuery sortable attached to it. But the receive function is never executed.  When I drag list item 10 to the 2nd position the way I expect this code to execute is to execute the receive function. But it never gets executed.  What am I doing wrong?

```
// Do the same for our playlist.
    $(".admin-left").sortable({
        opacity: '0.5',
        tolerance: "intersect",
        handle: ".handle",
        appendTo: 'appentToHolder',
        items: "li.admin-song",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            $(ui.item).css("opacity", "0.0").animate({ opacity: "1.0" }, "medium");
            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == "7.0") {
                $(ui.item).css("margin-bottom", "-6px");
            }
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            AddToLeftList(ui.item);
        },
        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(".admin-left li.ui-selected").removeClass("ui-selected");
            isDraggingSong = true;
            //soundManager.stopAll();
            //$(".btn-stop").removeClass("btn-stop");
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            CheckLeftList();

        },
        connectWith: '.sidebar-drop-box ul'
    }).selectable({ filter: 'li.admin-song', cancel: '.head *,.btn-stop,.btn-play,.notes,.btn-del,span.remove' }); // added .head * to fix bug# 1013
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that update, start, stop and connectWith functions are all working properly. What does the AddToLeftList function look like?

Comment: AddToLeftList Function sets a bunch of hidden fields, and also set all the css properties on the **UI** parameter.  I would have to assume all the rest of those functions are working because the i can move the list item.  I am using VS2008 and IE to test and step through the code, and it wont even step into the code during the drag or the drop.

Comment: @ChampionChris: My most used troubleshooting technique is to place an alert("HI"); statement after each line. As soon as you don't see it, the line above it is broken. But the code you posted seems like it should work just fine, especially if the other functions work.